# Page Redirect using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i am using jquery for login it is working fine but i have to redirect the login page on index.php page if success==1 else it will show the error. But it does not redirect on index page and remains on same login page.Can anyone please help me.This is my code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#form_login').submit(function() { 

                var uname= $('#username').val(); alert(uname);
                var password=$('#password').val(); alert(password);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/shop/admin/match_login.php",
                    data: {uname: uname, password:password},
                    success:function(data){
                    if(data==1){ alert("right");
                    var url='http://localhost/shop/admin/index.php';
                    $(location).attr('href',url);

                    }else{ alert("wrong");
                    $('#login-msg').html("Wrong User Name/Password");

                    }


                    } //call function after success
                });
                    return false;

            });
        }); 
</script>




session_start();
require_once("../utils/config.php");
require_once("../utils/functions.php");
require_once("../utils/dbClass.php");
require_once("../utils/database.php");
 $objNEWDB = new NEWMySQL;
 $host= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $url=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'];
 $hostnew=substr($url,0,-16);
 $user_name= $_POST['uname'];
 $password= $_POST['password']; 
 $SQL = "Select * from admin where UserName ='".$user_name."' and Password='".$password."'";
 $rsUser = $objNEWDB->select($SQL); //print_r($rsUser);
 //$res=mysql_fetch_array($rsUser); 
 if(sizeof($rsUser)==1 && $rsUser[0]['Status']=='1')
 {
    $_SESSION["session_admID"] = $rsUser[0]['AdminID']; 

 }
    echo $size= sizeof($rsUser);
```

Comment: Does the `alert("right")` show?

Comment: yes it alert the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

`document.location = url;`.

or

`document.location.href = url;`

Comment: One question. Are you trying to refresh the page or redirect to main page here?

Comment: yes i am getting 'right' alert. I am trying to redirect on main page.

Comment: thanks tpaksu its working with document.location.href = url; and going to index.php page i have use exit start of index.php page when i remove exit it come back on login back i have set session value on match_login.php page but it does not print any value of session on index.page. Can you please help me where i have to set session value. I have copy the match_login.php code above.

Comment: did you use `session_start()` at beginning of `match_login.php`?

Comment: yes i have insert session_start() at beginning. i have copy the code with above jquery code.

Comment: test with `print_r($_SESSION);` to see which sessions are set.

Comment: It is showing session value null like : Array ( ) on index.php page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22307/discussion-between-tpaksu-and-user1523311)

Comment: thanks a lot tpaksu i have checked session values with print_r($_SESSION) and it is showing null array then i have checked error in log file it is showing error-> Failed to write session data (files). Then i checked the session.save_path in php.ini file and changed it to session.save_path=/tmp and now it is working fine. Thanks a lot.......

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

to

```
location = url
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply `window.location = "http://localhost/shop/admin/index.php";`

Answer (score 0):

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://localhost/shop/admin/index.php");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://localhost/shop/admin/index.php";
```

Comment: window.location.replace is also not working i have tried all these but none of them working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> if(data==1) { window.location = "Page Url"; }

OR

> if(data==1) {window.location.href = "Page Url"; }

Also check whether the if loop is satisfied or not